# I have to google apps script that I want to have the data sorted automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script below that imports data automatically from several sheets via a master sheet that has a list of sheet IDs. I would like the data to be auto sorted by a specific column when the data is imported (like by date). Is there a way to do this?

```
  function customImport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Links');
  const outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  const columnNumberToFilter = 1

  const inputValues = inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, inputSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  const output = [];

  inputValues.forEach(entrie => {
    const [url, sheetname, range] = entrie;
    const sheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
      .getSheetByName(sheetname)
      .getRange(range)
    const data = sheetRange.getValues();
    data.forEach(row => {
      if (row[columnNumberToFilter - 1] != "") {
        output.push(row)
      }
    })
  })

outputSheet.getRange(2,1,outputSheet.getLastRow(), outputSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
outputSheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output)
}
```

Comment: "Like" by date, or by date? You will need to handle dates differently than say, alphabetically or numerically.

Comment: @NEWAZA, I want them ordered by date and then secondly by a start time (columns 4 and 5 respectively)

Comment: For simplest case you can try to add `.sort(4)` at the end of the last line: `outputSheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output).sort(4)`. It will sort the range by column 4. But it can sort wrong if there are strings with dates instead of date objects. Try it and see. It should work well for ISO formatted dates (YYYY-MM-DD) which I highly recommend to use. Less simply cases will need a more complicated solution

Comment: Have you tried something from the suggested solutions? Btw if you need to sort first by 4th column and then by 5th column you can chain the `sort()` methods: `range.sort(4).sort(5)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Sort by by Date

```
function sortColByDate(col = 1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.sort((a, b) => {
    let da = new Date(a[col - 1]).valueOf();
    let db = new Date(b[col - 1]).valueOf();
    return da - db
  })
   sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```